# ElasticSearch - use two range queries to find documents that match either or both of the queries

Tags: elasticsearch

The index has fields `discount_a` and `discount_b`.  I want to find documents where either `discount_a` is `"gte": 10` OR `discount_b` is `"gte": 15`.

I want the query to find documents that match one or both criteria.  I tried putting the `range` queries in the `should`, but this also returns documents that do not meet either criteria.

ElasticSearch version is 6.8.

Ideally I want to do something like this, except find documents that match *either* of the range queries, not necessarily both.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "discount_a": {
                            "gte": 10
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "discount_b": {
                            "gte": 15
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": []
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 500
}
```

Here's what I tried in the `should`

```
"should": [
{
                    "range": {
                        "discount_a": {
                            "gte": 10
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "discount_b": {
                            "gte": 15
                        }
                    }
                }
]
```

Comment: Paraphrasing to get the understanding right , is it right to say the following is the query ( (discount_a > 10) OR (discount_a > 10 AND discount_b > 15))

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G it would be `( (discount_a > 10) OR (discount_b > 15))`

Answer (score 0):

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "discount_a": {
              "gte": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "discount_b": {
              "gte": 15
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "minimum_should_match": "1"
  }
}
```